# Error: 404 Not Found: eslint-scope@https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-scope/-/eslint-scope-3.7.2.tgz

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am getting following error while running build from VSTS. *It works fine when building locally*.

```
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8311996Z 17219 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8312135Z 17220 warn enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'D:\a\1\s\client\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-ebde0b8d'
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8312272Z 17221 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8312389Z 17221 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8312514Z 17222 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: eslint-scope@https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-scope/-/eslint-scope-3.7.2.tgz
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8312662Z 17222 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8312812Z 17222 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8312977Z 17222 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8313134Z 17222 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8313293Z 17222 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8313451Z 17222 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8313602Z 17222 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8313755Z 17222 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8313958Z 17222 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8314086Z 17222 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8314194Z 17222 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8314348Z 17222 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8314450Z 17223 verbose cwd D:\a\1\s\client
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8314538Z 17224 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8314670Z 17225 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8314785Z 17226 verbose node v8.11.3
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8314868Z 17227 verbose npm  v5.6.0
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8314947Z 17228 error code E404
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8315065Z 17229 error 404 Not Found: eslint-scope@https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-scope/-/eslint-scope-3.7.2.tgz
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8315170Z 17230 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8315226Z 
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8367243Z ##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
2018-07-24T03:02:16.8378551Z ##[section]Finishing: npm install
```

I scanned my code as well as node_modules folder to check who is using **eslint-scope@3.7.2**, but surprisingly all the references either uses **eslint-scope "^3.7.1** or **eslint-scope@3.7.3**. Not sure from where eslint-scope@3.7.2 is comming from.

I am suspecting this to be a VSTS bug. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file here?

Comment: [package.json file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=126RZOAcJoltac-rbo0L1qVaczYbaw10R)

Comment: Do you also manage `node_modules`folder in your repo? What if you remove `node_modules`folder in your repo and build again? And what's the npm install log when you execute manually?

Comment: Beside, this is an similar issue https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9633, you can also check if it helps.

Comment: We don't keep `node_modules` folder in our repo. They gets downloaded on every build using `npm install`.

Comment: [github.com/npm/npm/issues/9633](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9633) didn't help

Comment: It worked after upgrading `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8"` package to `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.0-rc.3"`. I am still not sure what is wrong with `~0.6.8` version.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution here. And you can add the solution as answer and mark it later. It will also benefit others who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after upgrading `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8"` package to `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.0-rc.3"`. I am still not sure what is wrong with `~0.6.8` version.

Answer (score 0):

eslist-scope@3.7.2 was a malicious package that was unpubished from the registry for trying to steal NPM credentials. Full details can be found on the ESLint blogpost https://eslint.org/blog/2018/07/postmortem-for-malicious-package-publishes